# Function that Touches all the Local Maxima of another function

Tags: functions, curves, maxima-minima

I have a function: $$f(x)=\cos\left(\pi x\right)\cos\left(\frac{33}{x}\pi\right)-1$$ What I want to know is that is there such a function that is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ and "curves around" $f(x)$ at its local maxima. Now, I know that "curves around" is not rigorously defined, so here is a crudely drawn picture so there is a clearer picture about what I want:
[image]

Comment: Do you know anw smooth function which is *not* continuous?

Comment: If you take a function $f_n$ which is 1 away from $n$ and vanishes at $n$, then you might take $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n$.

Comment: @desiigner I edited my question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture shows that such a function is not uniquely determined, whatever the definition of "curving around". Even $f$ itself is "curving around" its local maxima. If you want a "simple" expression defining a function $g$ such that $g(x)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$ then note that $$-1\leq\cos{33\pi\over x}\leq1\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
and that the middle term here is very often $=\pm1$, especially in the interval $-{\pi\over2}\leq x\leq{\pi\over2}$. It follows that
$$g(x):=\bigl|\cos(\pi x)\bigr|-1$$
is a simple expression defining something like your blue curve.

[image]

Comment: Well someone offered me the same function, the problem is is that it is tangent to $f$, not touching its local maxima.

Comment: Also, I don't care how complex the function has to be (I'm sure it would have to be plenty complex to get a shape like I'm suggesting)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Christian Blatter, your problem is difficult and there will not be a unique solution. I was involved with such problems about a decade ago while working on a class of nonlinear problems. Unfortunately, I do not recall all of it. I do know, however, that what you need is the *sift* algorithm described by Huang *et al.*, https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1998.0193. This will give a robust solution to a variety of problems like this. The figures below are a quick and dirty solution that I carried out. You can see that that there are difficulties with the high frequency regime; this would probably be rectified with a higher resolution. Otherwise, it's alright. Also notice how far out I carried the calculation.
[image: Demo 1]

[image: Demo 2]

[image: Demo 3]

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing! How exactly did you get the equation for this? Is there an equation for this or is it just a drawing? If so, could you post the equation? Is there some code you can send me? I would love to take it apart :)

Comment: It's not an equation, but rather an algorithm. I did not write the code and am not at liberty to distribute it. It's part of Hilbert-Huang transform, or empirical mode decomposition (EMD). You can probably find code online in various languages. The actual program I used is the Matlab code sift.m.